# Codeigniter undefined variable in my case

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this strange error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeYVM.png

my hello.php in my controller

```
<?php

class Hello extends CI_controller {

    public function one($name){
        $this->load->view('one');
        $data = array("name" => $name);
    }
}
```

and this is my view one.php

```
<?php 

echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: you should know how to pass data to view.see codeigniter documentation https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing your `$data` array to your view file.  Just setting `$data` to an array won't do anything.

```
public function one($name){
    $data = array("name" => $name);
    $this->load->view('one', $data);
}
```

DOCS: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html